# How do i sort a text file into number order depending on the last digits?

Tags: c#

I've written this code with some help from others which rearranges the last few digits after a > symbol eg.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(SPFile);

var result = lines
  .AsParallel()
  .OrderBy(s => Convert.ToDouble(s.Split('>').Last()))
  .ToList();

File.WriteAllLines(SPFile2, result);
```

its works fine but now I want to include all the text on the same line and sort in the same way.
Here is what it looks like before.

```
 - 1st Hitman Hearns,Craig Nichol,K Dalgleish,9/2,N/A, >5.5
 - 2nd Discoverie,Henry Brooke,Kenneth Slack,7/2Favourite, >4.5
 - 3rd Aliandy,Thomas Bellamy,K C Bailey,9/2,N/A, >5.5
 - 4th Hear The Chimes,Maurice Linehan,S A Harris,10/1,N/A, >11
 - 5th Kilronan Castle,James Cowley,D Mccain Jnr,16/1,N/A, >17
```

I need the output file to look like this sorting the last digits smallest first

```
 - 2nd Discoverie,Henry Brooke,Kenneth Slack,7/2Favourite, >4.5
 - 1st Hitman Hearns,Craig Nichol,K Dalgleish,9/2,N/A, >5.5
 - 3rd Aliandy,Thomas Bellamy,K C Bailey,9/2,N/A, >5.5
 - 4th Hear The Chimes,Maurice Linehan,S A Harris,10/1,N/A, >11
 - 5th Kilronan Castle,James Cowley,D Mccain Jnr,16/1,N/A, >17
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using *anonymous class*:

```
...
.Select(line => new {
    line = line, // <- what we save (original line)
    order = ...  // <- criterium to sort on 
   })
.OrderBy(item => item.order) // order by criterium
.Select(item => item.line)   // but select original line
...
```

Implementation:

```
var result = File
  .ReadLines(SPFile)
  .AsParallel() // if you really want to use PLinq 
  .Select(line => new {
     line = line,
     order = Convert.ToDouble(line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(">") + 1)) })
  .OrderBy(item => item.order)
  .Select(item => item.line)
  .ToList(); 

File.WriteAllLines(SPFile, result);
```

**Edit**: in case

> "In some instances there is **no number** after the >..."

(see the comment below) you can slightly modify the Linq:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

var result = File
  .ReadLines(SPFile)
  .AsParallel() // if you really want to use PLinq 
  .Select(line => {
     double order;
     bool has = double.TryParse(
       line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(">") + 1), 
       NumberStyles.Any, 
       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
       out order);

     return new {
       line = line,
       order = order,
       has = has   
     };
    })
  .OrderByDescending(item => item.has) // or OrderBy(item => item.has)
  .ThenBy(item => item.order)
  .Select(item => item.line)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: In some instances there is no number after the > so how do you just put that line at the end of the file?

Comment: @Sean Probyn: then you can slightly modify the *Linq* (let's add `has` field into the anonymous object)

Comment: 2nd 20/1 Sliceoflife, Josephine Gordon, M Botti >21  
7th 50/1 Kyllachys Tale, Tom Marquand, R A Teal >51  
6th 7/1 Poets Charm, Martin Lane, S Crisford >8  
9th 14/1 Madam Prancealot, R Winston, P D Evans >15  
8th 6/1 Noble Ballad, S M Levey, R M Beckett >7  
3rd 3/1 Still Waiting, R Havlin, W Jarvis >4  
1st 9/4 Favourite, Elementary, G Baker, M L W Bell >3.25  
5th 5/1 License To Thrill, J F Egan, S Dow >6  
4th 20/1 Tigerfish, Hollie Doyle, W Stone >21  
6th 7/1 Poets Charm, Martin Lane, S Crisford >8  
7th 50/1 Kyllachys Tale, Tom Marquand, R A Teal >51

Comment: 8th 6/1 Noble Ballad, S M Levey, R M Beckett >7
9th 14/1 Madam Prancealot, R Winston, P D Evans >15

Comment: I don't understand how that worked? seems to be random

Comment: @Sean Probyn: let's be exact when parsing (`NumberStyles.Any,`           `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,` added into `double.TryParse`). Items which doesn't have any number after > appear *first* (if you want them being *last*, change `.OrderBy(item => item.has)` into `.OrderByDescending(item => item.has)`  )

Comment: I understand now how that works but I wanted the numbers showing lowest first then empty fields at the end

Comment: @Sean Probyn: in this case change `OrderBy(item => item.has)` to `.OrderByDescending(item => item.has)` (see my edit)

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'NumberStyles' and 'CultureInfo'  does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Sean Probyn: ensure `using System.Globalization;` is present

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure, the decimal point is converted correctly

```
var result = lines.AsParallel()
       .OrderBy(s => Convert.ToDouble(s.Split('>').Last(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
       .ToList();
```